# Concurrent access of c++ containers and memory arenas

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

If an `std::unordered_map` is accessed under `std::mutex` from multiple threads, what happens to the container on rebalancing/rehashing in terms of memory arenas?

[Threads have their own arena](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals). But in C++, memory allocation (doing `malloc`) isn't always up to you, like when containers reorganize themselves. So does that mean that upon such reorganization, the container will use the arena of the thread that happened to trigger it?

And if so, how does that affect performance, if parts of the container live in different arenas?